# How to send picture in push notifications to ionic 2 app

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ionic2, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

I tried with the following code to send a picture to my android app.

```
public class PushNotificationUtility {

    private static String SERVER_KEY = "MYSERVERKEY";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String title = "My First Notification";
        String message = "Hello, I'm push notification";
        sendPushNotification(title, message);
    }

    private static void sendPushNotification(String title, String message) throws Exception {
        // Create connection to send FCM Message request.
        URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + SERVER_KEY);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("to","/topics/MYTopic");
        JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
        info.put("title", title); // Notification title
        info.put("body", message); // Notification body
        info.put("picture","http://36.media.tumblr.com/c066cc2238103856c9ac506faa6f3bc2/tumblr_nmstmqtuo81tssmyno1_1280.jpg");
        info.put("summaryText","Summary");
        json.put("notification", info);


        // Send FCM message content.
        OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(json.toString().getBytes());

        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());
    }
}
```

I am able to send the notification to the Android device but not the picture. I want to send the picture along with the message. Is there anything that I have to do on the client side to display picture?

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `picture` property on [FCM notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options), what you can do is use the `data` property to send and object of important data you want to use in your app when the user receives an push, create it with a property `picture` with your image link:

```
let data = {
  picture: 'http://36.media.tumblr.com/c066cc2238103856c9ac506faa6f3bc2/tumblr_nmstmqtuo81tssmyno1_1280.jpg'
};
info.put("data", data); // Notification data
```

And in your receiving push method you can grab this property and show the picture.

```
myPlugin.on('notification', notification => {
  console.log(notification); // JUST TO SEE THE CALLBACK STRUCTURE
  this.myImage = notification.data.picture;
});
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: I want image to be displayed as a part of the notification just like an advertisement of some offers. Not as some data. Usually we see these kind of notifications in shopping apps.

Comment: @user1188867 oh got it. As far as i know FCM cordova plugins doesn't support this kind of notification. Ionic.io notifications also doesn't support it. I think this is more native or no one has manage to do this with plugins yet. But here's an Android tutorial of how to achieve this http://androidbash.com/firebase-push-notification-android/